# Can xdg-open open a different browser for specific URLs?

Tags: xdg-open

I'd like xdg-open to use a non-default browser when I click a work related link.

Maybe I could configure xdg-open to call a script when opening URLs. The script could open a different browser based on the URL host. It would be ideal, though, if xdg-open can do it without the script.